# How to match a line from text file with a string which is present in it?

Tags: python, arrays, regex, string

I need to match every index of my string array with text file and if there is a match found I need complete matching line.But my code is not doing anything.

Here is my code:

```
for element in array:
    elementstring=''.join(element)
    with open(file_location,mode="r", encoding='utf8') as file:
    reader=file.readlines()
    for line in reader:
         words=re.split(' ',line)
         if elementstring in line:
              print(line)
```

Comment: Fix your indentation. The body of `with:` needs to be indented more.

Comment: If `element` is a string, why do you need `''.join(element)`?

Comment: What's the purpose of the `words` variable?

Comment: You don't need to reread the file each time through the loop. Set `reader` once outside the loop.

Comment: What is the line `words=re.split(' ', line)` meant to do?  Maybe the second to last line should be `if elementstring in words:`?

Comment: @Phillip Although if there's no match for the string in the line, there won't be a match for it in the list of words, either.

Comment: Assuming your indentation is correct in the real script, and this is just a copying error, your code looks like it should work. Can you show a sample value of `array` and the file contents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do it fairly efficiently in the sense that it only makes one pass through the file, doesn't read it all into memory at once, and checks each line for all possible words.

```
file_location = 'somefile.txt'
words = 'word1', 'word2', 'word3'

with open(file_location, mode="r", encoding='utf8') as file:
    for line in (line.rstrip() for line in file):
         if any((word in line) for word in words):
              print('matches: {!r}'.format(line))
```